# Are these acceptable gradient differences in my gradient checking implementation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I am building a CNN with a couple FC layers to predict classes depicted in images.

Architecture:

X -> CNN -> ReLU -> POOL -> FC -> ReLU -> FC -> SOFTMAX -> Y_hat

I am implementing gradient checking to check that my implementation of gradient descent is correct. I read that an acceptable difference is somewhere on the order of 10e-9. Do the differences below look acceptable?

```
Epoch: 0
Cost: 2.8568426944476157
Numerical Grad           Computed Grad
-5.713070134419862e-11   -6.616929226765933e-11
-5.979710331310053e-11   -6.94999613415348e-11
-5.87722383797037e-11    -6.816769371198461e-11
-5.948114792212038e-11   -6.905587213168474e-11
-5.756886551189494e-11   -6.683542608243442e-11
-5.995452767971952e-11   -6.94999613415348e-11
-5.772401095738584e-11   -6.705747068735946e-11
-5.5480026579651e-11     -6.439293542825908e-11
-5.8138150324971285e-11  -6.727951529228449e-11
-5.76037967235867e-11    -6.683542608243442e-11
```

For reference, here is my implementation of gradient checking:

```
def gradient_check(self, layer):
    # get grads from layer
    grads = layer.backward_cache['dW']
    # flatten layer W
    shape = layer.W.shape
    W_flat = layer.W.flatten()

    epsilon = 0.001

    print('Numerical Grad', 'Computed Grad')
    # loop through first few W's
    for i in range(0, 10):
        W_initial = W_flat[i]
        W_plus = W_initial + epsilon
        W_minus = W_initial - epsilon

        W_flat[i] = W_plus
        layer.W = W_flat.reshape(shape)
        cost_plus = self.compute_cost(self.forward_propogate())

        W_flat[i] = W_minus
        layer.W = W_flat.reshape(shape)
        cost_minus = self.compute_cost(self.forward_propogate())

        computed_grad = (cost_plus - cost_minus) / (2 * epsilon)

        print(grads.flatten()[i], computed_grad)

        # reset layers W's
        W_flat[i] = W_initial
        layer.W = W_flat.reshape(shape)

    return layer
```

Comment: 1e-11 is basically 0 so I would argue that the data you are checking this on makes little sense (if all "true" gradients are below the interesting precision, equally acceptable code would be "return 0")

Comment: the data is a set of images, each representing one of 7 classes. i had previously trained the model to accurately predict the classes (on the training set only). could you explain what you mean by "makes little sense" in this case? thank you.

Comment: Gradients presented in the output you are refering to are so tiny that equally correct gradient estimate would be to output 0s. I guess your learning rate was huge to deal with this issue, or maybe later in training these gradients grow; or maybe these are degenerated 10 dimensions and on remaining ones values are higher. Either way - for the sake of the question asked (checking **numerical accuracy** of gradients computation, something that outputs values of order 1e-11 all the time will be hard to check estimation of)

Comment: To preface, I am new to ML and more complicated things like CNN's. I'm trying to build my own from scratch. I noticed that if I removed the ReLU activation after the initial CNN, the training was a lot faster. I posted the architecture above for reference.

Comment: Instead of printing each dimension of the gradient - measure L2 distance between the gradients (or other norm/statistics, like min/max error etc.). This will give you more proper picture.

Comment: ok will do, thank you!

Comment: There are also existing methods to do this check, like https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.check_grad.html

Answer (score 1):

After researching the cause for gradients closet to zero, I discovered my network may be suffering from the problem of gradient plateaus. The solution to this is to add one or all of the following: momentum, RMS prop, or Adam optimization. I will attempt to implement Adam optimization, since it encapsulates both momentum and RMS prop, and if this works, I will mark my answer as correct.

Followup edit: Unfortunately, when I implemented Adam, this only resulted in exploding gradients. Even with a very small learning rate 1e-5. I did make some progress increasing the numerical gradients by adding two more conv->relu->pool layers. But either way the gradient computations don't seem right. The issue must be with my implementation of backprop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this formula to see the relative error between those numbers:

diff = (|grads - computed_grad|)/(|grads| + |computed_grad|)

With the correct implementation, it is expected to be less than 1e-7.

see: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-debug-a-neural-network-with-gradient-checking-41deec0357a9